# Wrting a large string into file in php

Tags: php, database, string

I am building a large string out from database, sometimes it gets in MB's . Is there a way to write the string to file after its size cross certain limits ( bytes). My concern is to free memory as soon as possible. On the other side the idea of opening a file resource and writing to it after certain intervals seems useless because of disk-latency etc ..

a) So how do you manage large string concatenation and saving it to a file ?

b) Are there any SPL classes to manage this kind of activity to boost performance or we are the mercy of  beloved (.) dot operator ?

Comment: Seeing as the data you are getting from the database will come as one huge string, there is probably no way to do it any other way. You could write data into the file sequentially but it seems pointless if the source data is 100% present straight away

Comment: no the string is gradually concatenated i.e  `foreach row`

Comment: Then why not use good old http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php for sequential writing? Should work fine

Comment: Depends on your database and what exactly you're doing. If it supports it, you can open a stream handle to a BLOB object in the database and stream it right through to a file. The data will not be stored in memory at all, it just flows right through PHP. Postgres + PDO + BLOB types support this, I'm not sure about other databases.

Comment: @deceze Unfortunately I am using Mysql. Things could have otherwise done within Postgres SQL/PL to speedup things

Comment: @Pekka웃 , thanks my concern was disk latency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write it to the disk for every row. This will minimize the amount of RAM being used at any given time and the disk latency should be about the same.

```
$fp = fopen('filename.txt', 'w');

while($row = // query stuff) {
    fwrite($fp, $row['column']);
}
fclose($fp);
```